# Retrieve data from via UART

Tags: java, uart

I am using UART to get the input to my system from PIC Development Board. and I use the following code to get the values from the board.

```
public SerialReader( InputStream in ) {
            this.in = in;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[ 1024 ];
            int len = -1;
            try {
                /*len = this.in.read(buffer);
                int x = buffer[0] & 0xff;
                System.out.println(buffer[0]);
                System.out.println(x);
                System.out.println((char)x);*/
                while( ( len = this.in.read( buffer ) ) > -1 ) {
                    System.out.print( new String( buffer, 0, len ) );
                    System.out.println(len);
                    /*String s = new String(buffer); //buffer.toString();  1                    
                    System.out.println(s);
                    for (int i=0; i<=buffer.length; i++)
                        System.out.println(buffer[i]);
                    //System.out.print( new String( buffer, 0, len ) );
*/          }   
            } catch( IOException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Output: ààà

Expected Output:  #C01=0155,INT=16:11,OUT=05:11

How do I retrive the expected output.

Comment: Have you configured both the PIC and Java serial ports to match baud rate, parity etc.? Have you confirmed that the PIC output is correct by using a terminal emulation program?